# How do i get this

Tags: sectioning, formatting, symbols, header-footer

I am currently trying to get this display, and i can't figure out if a package is needed for it or anything? [image]

Also, i don't know the word for this in english, so how to i do this so that i add these at the end of each page for a reference? [image]

Comment: ...by "these" are you referring to the rule/line or the number-and-text or both? What does the number represent... the page number?

Comment: i dont know what they are called, but im talking about adding a little "1" in the text, and if i click on it it sends me to the bottom of the pages with the text corresponding to "1", as appears in the second picture

Comment: It's a footnote, "note de bas de page", in French ;)   https://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/footnote.html

Comment: @SebGlav thank you i couldn't find the english word, this helps me out a lot!

Comment: @needle: For reference, this question is poorly constructed as the title provides no context and the pictures don't even tell the whole story. It also shows no research effort.

Comment: noted i will no longer do this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\shadowbox{Essai}
\end{document}
```

For the second, you should only ask one thing per question asked.

Comment: noted i will no longer ask multiple questions as one. But can you still help me out for the second one?

Comment: See my comment on OP.